# Filter according to two conditions that are in dynamic dependence

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having a large dataset with a value called `CPE` and a percentage `PERC`. In real world it's slightly different, but I reduced it to the minimum necessary.

```
| CPE|      PERC|
|---:|---------:|
|  42| 0.1132664|
| 264| 0.9260718|
| 470| 0.3732287|
| 316| 0.7437126|
|   9| 0.5819554|
| 114| 0.2052649|
```

Now I want to filter. Smaller amounts of `CPE` require a higher `PERC` to get in focus.

Surely I could do it this way:

```
df[(CPE > 20 & PERC > 0.95) |
     (CPE > 50 & PERC > 0.9) |
     (CPE > 100 & PERC > 0.85) |
     (CPE > 250 & PERC > 0.8)]
```

But as there can be many more in real world and additionally they can vary from time to time, I'm looking for an easier and more dynamic solution. 
Something like creating a list with all combinations and then using each combination as a filter-condition-pair.

```
list(c(20, 0.95), c(50, 0.9), c(100,0.85), c(250,0.8))
```

Is there a smart way to handle this? Even if I'm preferring `data.table`, `dplyr` is great as well. And it haven't be a list, I'm open for any similar approach.

---

**MWE**

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(33)

df = data.table(CPE=sample(1:500, 100), 
                PERC=runif(min = 0.1, max = 1, n=100))
```

Comment: Are those value thresholds custom or should that be dynamically adjusted from the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `list` is already created, we can loop over the `list`, create the logical condition with the first and second element using `CPE` and `PERC` columns respectively, `Reduce` to a single logical vector with `|` and subset the data

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(lst1, \(x) CPE > x[1] & PERC > x[2]))]
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c(20, 0.95), c(50, 0.9), c(100,0.85), c(250,0.8))
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(purrr)

df <- structure(list(CPE = c(42L, 264L, 470L, 316L, 9L, 114L), PERC = c(0.1132664, 
0.9260718, 0.3732287, 0.7437126, 0.5819554, 0.2052649)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

constraints <- structure(list(CPE = c(20, 50, 100, 250), PERC = c(0.95, 0.9, 
0.85, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

constraints
#>   CPE PERC
#> 1  20 0.95
#> 2  50 0.90
#> 3 100 0.85
#> 4 250 0.80

filt <- 
  map2(df, constraints, outer, '>') %>% 
    reduce(`&`) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    reduce(`|`)

df %>% 
  filter(filt)
#>   CPE      PERC
#> 1 264 0.9260718
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>